# Compare two text files string by string in java

Tags: java

I have two text files and I want to compare the contents of text files using java.

For example  First file **e1.txt** has the content `"hello this is india"` , and another **e2.txt** contents `"hello this is usa"`. I want the output should be the text which is not similer in both files(here output should be india or usa).

Problem which I was facing here is that java IO method reads line by line so in this case no output will be given(both lines are different), also white spaces should be ignored. 
I will be very much thankful if anyone will help me in this problem.

Here is my Code :

```
 public void fh() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File f1=new File("C:\\\\Users\\\\Ramveer\\\\Desktop\\\\idrbt Project\\\\e1.txt");
    File f2=new File("C:\\\\Users\\\\Ramveer\\\\Desktop\\\\idrbt Project\\\\e2.txt");
    FileInputStream fi1=new FileInputStream(f1);
    FileInputStream fi2=new FileInputStream(f2); 
    DataInputStream di1=new DataInputStream(fi1);
    BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(di1));
    DataInputStream di2=new DataInputStream(fi2);
    BufferedReader br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(di2));
    String s1, s2;  
    while ((s1=br1.readLine())!=null && (s2=br2.toString())!=null) 
     {
    if(!s1.equals(s2)){
    System.out.println(s1);
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please format your code :)

Comment: does word order matter? i mean should it return the same result for comparing "hello this is india" to "hello this is usa" and "hello india this is" to "hello this is usa"?

Comment: You should learn how to debug. Insert a breakpoint and step through the lines. Watch your variables and see what value they have. You'll find your problem and be able to solve it soon enough.

Comment: i think it is readable now

Comment: Try `java.util.Scanner`

Comment: Why not use a `Scanner` to read with delimiter set to whitespace?

Comment: @Joetjah I love 'learn how to debug' comments, but in this case it is NOT appropriate. He knows exactly why the code is wrong but not how to fix it, it's not a debugging problem.

Comment: @Patashu You are right, I was slightly too quick.

Comment: @RamveerSingh I do wonder.. You say `so in this case no output will be given(both lines are different)`, but doesn't this `if(!s1.equals(s2)){ System.out.println(s1); }` actually print the line if they are different??

Comment: You are invoking toString on the second reader. Probably not what you want.

Comment: till strings are same ,no result should be there,but when strings come different ,the different string should be return,for my case order matters. More precise  if i have text1 string ram, text2 string syam ,ram  or syam should be the output.

Comment: Two backslashes in a string literal represent one backslash char: `"C:\\Users..."`. Also add an encoding to the `InputStreamReader(InputStream, "UTF-8")` or so. And leave out DataInputStream.

Comment: @RamveerSingh So in your case, you have two different lines so one of the output should be given, correct? `so in this case no output will be given(both lines are different` is what you said, which is different.

Comment: @Joetjah really sorry , just understand the problem.. text1 hello this is india, text2 hello this is usa, i want the output usa or india ignoring the white space also .

Comment: @Joetjah output can also be  the different part or same part of lines.{'hello this is' can also be output}

Answer (score 3):

Just as what I commented, use `java.util.Scanner`

```
public static void fha(InputStream is1, InputStream is2) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(is1);
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(is2);
    while (sc1.hasNext() && sc2.hasNext()) {
        String str1 = sc1.next();
        String str2 = sc2.next();
        if (!str1.equals(str2))
            System.out.println(str1 + " != " + str2);
    }
    while (sc1.hasNext())
        System.out.println(sc1.next() + " != EOF");
    while (sc2.hasNext())
        System.out.println("EOF != " + sc2.next());
    sc1.close();
    sc2.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the StringTokenizer class, and the String.indexOf(String s) method.

You can use a StringTokenizer to break-up a String into sections, separated by delimiters.

You can use String.indexOf(String s) to find a particular String within another String.

You can probably solve your problem using a combination of these.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want the comparison go (e.g. word by word, char by char), i.e. given

```
 Hello this is India
```

and

```
 Hello this is Indonesia
```

should it output:

1. "India"/"Indonesia"?
2. "ia" vs. "onesia"?

In any case, you can use `br1.read()` and `br2.read()` to do a character by character comparison (case 2).  Or you could use loops to read each file until the next delimiter (space maybe) and then compare the words.

Comment: comparison is word by word.these are simple lines ,we can use loop until next space, but what else if i have many lines in text files and how would you determine the no of words.

Comment: a line end could also be treated as end of word (this is common).  So read word loouped until char is ' ' or '\n' or '\r'.  Do this on each file and then output different words.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;

public class CompareTextFiles {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

      FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\text1.txt");
      FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\text2.txt");

      DataInputStream in1= new DataInputStream(fstream1);
      DataInputStream in2= new DataInputStream(fstream2);

      BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
      BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));

      String strLine1, strLine2;


      while((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null && (strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null){
          if(strLine1.equals(strLine2)){
              System.out.println(strLine1);

          }
      }
    }
}
```